# Firestore's timestamp in array has strange behavior

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning firestore recently.

I want to implement below data structure.

```
- user (document)
  - schedules(field, array)
    - 0(map)
      - startTime(tiemstamp)
      - endTime(timestamp)
    - 1(map)
      - startTime(tiemstamp)
      - endTime(timestamp)
```

I wanted to operate adding a testdata in firestore's GUI. so I created a `schedules`(array) and `0`(map)'s data(include startTime and endTime). after that I added `1`(map)'s data(include startTime and endTime). At that moment, `0`(map)'sdata was automatically changed to below data structure.

```
    - 0(map)
      - startTime(object)
        - nanoseconds(number) (changed to 0)
        - seconds(number) (changed to 1550502000)
      - endTime(object)
        - nanoseconds(number) (changed to 0)
        - seconds(number) (changed to 1550504000)
    - 1(map)
      - startTime(tiemstamp)
      - endTime(timestamp)
```

why timestamp was automatically changed to object?

Please teach me.

[image]

Comment: Does it happen in any collection? What if you use a different field name instead of schedules? Are there any cloud functions?

Comment: It happen in any collection.
it is same result when different field name instead of schedules.
there is no functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to reproduce the problem, it seems to be a bug with the Firebase console, not with Firestore itself, because it only happens on the console.

You should report it to Google: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

In the meantime, though, what you can do is add the test data through code, using any language that supports the Admin SDK.

Example in Node:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
// ...

await admin.firestore().collection('test-date').add({
    schedule: [
        {

            startDate: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
            endDate: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
        },
        {
            startDate: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
            endDate: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
        },
    ]
});
```